# GTK: how to get width and height of GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON etc?

Tags: gtk

I need to add my own images into GTK Icon Theme, so i need to somehow figure the size in pixels GTK uses to display icons of different predefined sizes: `GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON`, `GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU`, `GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG` etc. GTK manual states that sizes are available as value of `gtk-icon-sizes` property of `GtkSetting`s object. I have executed following code on latest ubuntu:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk; print(gtk.settings_get_default().get_property('gtk-icon-sizes'))
```

But the output is very short:

```
'panel-menu=22,22;gtk-button=16,16'
```

Where can i find rest of the sizes, for example for `GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG` or `GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK resizes the icons to whatever size they need to be. According to the [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#install_icons), you should make at least one 48x48 icon, and optionally a scalable SVG icon. That is enough to be able to display any of those sizes.

The [Tango Icon Theme Guidelines](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Theme_Guidelines#Sizes) recommend some supplementary sizes that you can make, in order to minimize how often the icon has to be resized internally by GTK.

Comment: Thanks. But how GTK knows what pixel size is `GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR` if no such value is in `gtk-icon-sizes`? Is it hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: Nope, it is specified by the theme, I believe.

Comment: @erick And no API available to get such size? :(. One of my icons need to be dynamically generated (not from file) so i need to know size in pixels of surround icons so my generated icon fits.

Comment: You should get th size of the window (widget's window), where you want to paint your icon, and then make your icon relative to that size.

Comment: Can't you just rescale your pixbuf to GTK_ICON_SIZE_WHATEVER without knowing how many pixels that is?

Comment: @ptomato Yes, but i RENDER the icon, so i need to know it's width and height in pixels in order to set this pixels into require colors :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add your images to the icon list with gtk_icon_theme_add_builtin_icon, and then use them as named icons.

An example in Vala:

```
Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf;
pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf.from_file_at_size(Path.build_filename(AutovalaPluginConstants.DATADIR,"valaplugin","application.svg"),-1,-1);
Gtk.IconTheme.add_builtin_icon("autovala-plugin-executable",-1,pixbuf);
```